# Como utilizar o artisan make:migration em um subdiretório com o Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5, migrations

Estou começando a construir uma aplicação extremamente robusta utilizando o laravel 5 e preciso organizar todos os meus códigos de migração de tabelas. Minha solução foi estruturar subpastas para que facilite o entendimento e a modularização desta aplicação. O problema é que não consigo criar minhas migrations dentro de subdiretórios da "migrations".

O que procuro é algo como isso:

```
php artisan make:migration Foo/create_table_foo
php artisan make:migration Foo/upgrade_table_foo
```

O problema é que nao consigo gerar esse tipo de estrutura, ao fazer isso o artisan insere a data no nome da pasta e diz que não conseguiu encontrar o diretório. Como resolver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrei uma solução direto na documentação. Devo utilizar o método `--path` dizendo qual o diretório será salvo as migrations. Assim:

```
php artisan make:migration create_table_foo --path=database/migrations/Foo
```